# 3D audio with PortAudio and libaudiodecoder

Tags: c++, portaudio

I wanted to know whether it is possible to realize a 3D sound using the listed libraries? if so, how?

At the moment I can only play and rewind mp3. Using this library I want to play sounds in the my 3D game.